# How to save dist/build files on Github Release but not in master

Tags: git, github

I'm building a library and the process generates files in `/dist`, a directory that I have ignored from versioning. In order to deploy the library, I'd like to have `/dist/*` files in a Github Release but not committed to the master, as I found JQuery's developers does it:

- [jquery/branch/master/dist](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/dist)
- [jquery/tag/3.3.1/dist](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/32b00373b3f42e5cdcb709df53f3b08b7184a944/dist)

But, I can't find a way to do that. Also, I'm not sure if it is a good practice, but it seems clean.

I appreciate your help.

Best,
Alvaro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What jquery is doing is to create what you might call an "anonymous branch".  That is, from a topological standpoint each release is branched away from `master`, and on that branch they create the `dist` folder; but they don't create what git calls a branch (or, at least, they don't preserve it); instead they keep the "anonymous branch" alive by putting a tag at the end of it.

For example, if you're on master and ready to create a release from the current version, you could

```
git checkout --detach
# generate the dist/ folder
git commit -m 1.0.37
git tag v1.0.37
git checkout master
# continue development
```

and you'll end up with something like

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F <--(master)
      \         \         \
       B+        D+        F+
        ^v1.0.17  ^v1.0.25  ^v1.0.37
```

The tagged versions have the dist folders, and the mainline doesn't.

That's "how".  You also ask if it's a good solution.  It's not one I would use personally, but there's generally no technical harm in it.  If you want the deployment packages in your repo, this is a way to do it.

(I would be more inclined to package them using npm, or nuget, or maven, or etc. as appropriate; and keep them correspondingly in an artifact repo.  But if the deployment packages aren't huge, or at least are similar from version to version so that delta compression might keep them from adding to much bulk to the repo, then I can see where you might find advantages to having them integrated into the history / all in one place.)

I guess the bottom line is, debating whether a solution is "clean" is usually fruitless, because it's far too subjective a term.  If you can translate that into objectively measurable criteria, you can then decide if your solution meets those criteria.  My personal criteria favor using deployment tools to deploy, and using git for source control only; but many people get good mileage out of combining those functions if the deployment needs are simple.

Comment: Add `git push --tags` to update the release on Github